# How to apply a method to all values in Enum class?

Tags: python, enums

I have some `Enum`s which may or may not have clashing names but are in different modules, so I want to apply some sort of prefix / suffix lambda to make them unique without having to manually specify it for each value. How can I alter my `Enum` class definitions to do something like the following? Thanks!

```py
# foo.py
class Ids(Enum):
  # define some accessor lambda or dunder override?
  some_id = auto()
  # many more...


# bar.py
class Ids(Enum):
  # define some accessor lambda or dunder override?
  some_id = auto()
  # many more...


# baz.py
from foo import Ids as FooIds
from bar import Ids as BarIds

print(FooIds.some_id)  # foo-some_id
print(BarIds.some_id)  # bar-some_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `auto()` however you want (note, the implementation may be different depending on your Python version, I'm on `3.9.15` here):

```py
from enum import auto, Enum


# foo.py
class Ids(Enum):
    def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values):
        return f"foo-{count+1}"

    ID1 = auto()
    ID2 = auto()


# bar.py
class Ids(Enum):
    def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values):
        return f"bar-{count+1}"

    ID1 = auto()
    ID2 = auto()
```

output (both defined in same iPython session as `FooIds` and `BarIds`, respectively):

```py
In [2]: FooIds.ID1
Out[2]: <FooIds.ID1: 'foo-1'>

In [3]: BarIds.ID1
Out[3]: <BarIds.ID1: 'bar-1'>
```

Is there some particular reason you're using `Enum` here though? Why do you have two separate Enums doing almost the same thing?

Comment: Awesome. Fair question. In this case, I'm using them to keep track of component IDs in our Dash app: https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks. The app has many pages contributed to by various users who may not be aware of other pages existing IDs. So if two users both happen to label a component ID as "foo", I want the framework to be smart enough to handle that case.